# How to fetch primary key in GridView but don't display it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using `<asp:GridView></asp:GridView>` I am trying to display columns of database table. I want to fetch primary key of table but obviously don't want to display it. How can I achieve this?
This is my GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" BorderColor="#0066FF" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="MyGrid_RowEditing" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowDeleting="MyGrid_RowDeleting"
         OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" EmptyDataText="No Value" BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="Solid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PrimaryKey" HeaderText="UserId"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Column3" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I also tried `visible=false` to hide primary key, it hides primary key from displaying but also don't fetch its value and I want this value.
Hope my question is clear.

Comment: `Visible="false"` do not allows your column to render, however where you need to access your Primary Key ??

Comment: I need primary key in code behind

Comment: to edit or delete any row of that table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set Visible = false within the [OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx) event, this will mean the data is still accessible to you, but won't display on the page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" BorderColor="#0066FF" 
    AllowPaging="false" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"      
    OnRowEditing="MyGrid_RowEditing" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
    OnRowDeleting="MyGrid_RowDeleting"
    OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" EmptyDataText="No Value" 
    BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="Solid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PrimaryKey" HeaderText="UserId"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Column3" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In Codebehind:

```
protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:GridView ... DataKeyNames="PrimaryKey" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PrimaryKey" visible="false" HeaderText="PKId"/>
```

Also use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/80964/How-to-get-Hidden-Column-Value-in-GridView)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PrimaryKey" visible="false" HeaderText="UserId"/>
```

To get Primary Key

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" BorderColor="#0066FF" DataKeyNames="PrimaryKey"
```

---

```
MyGrid.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value
```

OR

```
MyGrid.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].DataBoundItem
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a column by its name instead of its index in GridView. After creating DataTable or Dataset, you have to find the index of the column by its name then save index in global variable like ViewStae, Session and etc and then call it in RowDataBound, like the example:

```
string headerName = "Id";
            DataTable dt = .... ;

            for (int i=0;i<dt.Columns.Count;i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == headerName)
                {
                    ViewState["CellIndex"] = i;

                }

            }

      ... GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CellIndex"]);

            e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
        }                        
    }
```